# Should I change my upgraded database's compatibility level from 8 to 9?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, compatibility-level

I am planning to **upgrade** a SQL Server 2000 instance to a SQL Server 2005 instance.

I am not going to change any database code, so I won't be taking advantage of any SQL2005 specific syntax. Is there any reason to set my compatibility higher (to level 9)? Or is it ok to leave at compatibility level 8?

Comment: I'd be forced to wonder why are you upgrading, if that is the case?

Comment: Let's assume the client wants to move onto a later platform and will have other databases that will make use of SQL2005 features. They prefer not to have to maintain a SQL 2000 and 2005 instance at the same time, hence the upgrade.

Comment: OK, kinda early in the morning here, that sounds very reasonable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to look at this:

- If you want to change your code (or
  install some collaborating
  SQL2005/2008 servers) in the future,
  your compatibility mode will affect
  that decision
- If you haven't run the
  Upgrade Adviser, you may not be able
  to upgrade :) compatibility level 9
  *disables* certain syntaxes and features that were available in 8.

So, simple answer is no you don't have to increase your compat level, but then you've to consider your future with this box too :)

Answer (score 2):

Its fine to leave it at 8 until you wish to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small point - compat level 90 drops support for the old ANSI-89 outer join syntax (`*=`, `=*`). If you do decide to switch, make sure you have checked your code base for those first.

Comment: Definitely, thanks. I see there are a number of subtle things that are not supported in level 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Well Reports that u get with level 90, is very nice... that alone is incentive to upgrade...

Comment: I Don't think you understood it, he is talking about the databases compatibility level not SQL Version Features.

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility level is not just a question of preference, its a matter of how you use the database
you can check what changed on this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

So unless you know that changing the compatibility level will not break anything you should definetly upgrade. So do a thoroughly check before taking any chances.